# Looping with list comprehensions

Tags: python

To simplify what I am trying to do:

I have 50 employees, each with a 40 task capacity.

I have a dataframe that I am reading in from a SQL table that I want to filter down to tasks with a score equal to 10 and then assign them to each employee so they have a full "basket" or workload. I want to assign one task to each employee and then iterate until finished.

My final output would look like a list with each list based off of position, denoting the employee number and the tasks that are assigned to them.

```py
final_basket = [[task1, task2,...] , [task8, task11], ...[task45,task4]]
```

each one of the lists within the final basket would correspond to an employee, example:

`final_basket[0] = [task1, task2,...]` would be all the tasks for the first employee.

I can assign a task to each employe fine, but I get stuck with re-looping over all the employees to fill their capacity.

```
def basket_builder(i):
    agent_basket = [[ ] for basket in range(40)] #define empty basket for all 40 agents 
    score_10 = base_data_1_mo[base_data_1_mo.case_score == 10] #filter data to score 10 only 
    score_10 = score_10[['investigation_id']] #select only investigation id df 
    score_10 = score_10.sort_index() ##sort by index asc 
    for i in range(40):
        investigation_id = score_10.iloc[0]['investigation_id']
        agent_basket[i].append(investigation_id)
        index_drop_v2 = score_10[score_10.investigation_id == investigation_id].index[0]
        score_10 = score_10.drop([index_drop_v2])
        return final_basket

for i in range(40):
    final_basket = []
    final_basket = [[basket_builder(i) for agent in agent_basket[i]] 

final_basket
```

Since I made some modifications to use a function to try and loop over here, I am now having an issue even printing the `final_Basket`

Comment: I think you should iterate over the list of tasks instead of iterating on the list of users

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  "I am having an issue" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do it with something like:

```
employee_task = {}
for n, task in enumerate(tasks):
   employee_number = n % 50
   if employee_number not in employee_task:
      employee_task[employee_number] = []
   employee_task[employee_number].append(task)
```

and check a posteriori that each employee has less than 40 tasks